# Android: How to set listeners for dynamically created items in a list view

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have list view that populated its items based on a list of names. I've added an adapter to the list view and set items. Here's the code:

```
    items = new String[]{ "Apple", "Banana" };
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.fruits_listView);

    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruits, R.id.list_fruits_textView, items) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_fruits_imageView);

            // Change icon based on name and set click listener for it
            String s = items[position];

            if (s.equals("Apple"))
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(appleListener);
            }
            else if (s.equals("Banana"))
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.banana);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(bananaListener);
            }

            return v;
        }
    });

    // Setup listeners
    appleListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Apple.class));
        }
    };

    bananaListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Banana.class));
        }
    };
```

However when I click the list items nothing happens, seems listeners don't work. Any idea what my problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just initialize your listeners before setting the adapters. 
I hope this solves your problem.

**EDIT:**
Set these properties in your `ListView`

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Also make your `ImageView(s)` clickable:

```
yourImageViewObject.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: As you said I also tried that. I set and initialized each image-view listener right after I set the image resource but it ain't work.

Comment: This should even work with initializing the listeners after setting the adapter as the views are being created later. Also setting the properties as described in this answer is not necessary for your provided code as you set the listeners explicitly on the views. Can you say if the ``onClick()`` methods get called (e.g. using a brake point)? Do you have any exceptions on the Android log?

Comment: @LarsBlumberg Actually no. I didn't get any exception. It simply didn't work.

Comment: Maybe I should only use list view onItemClickListener.

Comment: Using ``onItemClickListener`` is generally the preferred idea.

Comment: `imageView.setClickable(true)` this is what you need, i think.

Comment: You should also make a subClass of `ArrayAdapter` where you implement all the required methods including the `getView(...)` Method. Then set it to your `ListView`.

Comment: @SalmanAyub Sorry, yesterday I was busy so I couldn't try your way. It didn't make any change, but thanks for your kind help buddy.